# How to add "caption" tag in TableBlock template in StreamField?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'd like to add `<caption>` tag for tables created with TableBlock in StreamField, to make the tables more accessible and semantically correct. Right now, the default template doesn't have that tag. I'm not sure how I should be customizing the `table.html` template (from the default, and I'm not sure how to render the table if I make a custom class for the table block to add captioning.
`<caption>` must be `<table>`'s first child, that's why I need to tinker with the template. Anyone has doe this before?

```
<table>
    <caption>Example Caption</caption> <--- Need this here
    <thead>
        <th>Header col 1</th>
        <th>Header col 2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell col 1</td>
        <td>Cell col 2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following code.

TableBlock.py

```
class TableHead(blocks.StructBlock):
    table_head_text = blocks.ListBlock(blocks.CharBlock(max_length=120))

class TableRow(blocks.StructBlock):
    table_row_text = blocks.ListBlock(blocks.CharBlock(max_length=120))

class TableBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    caption_text = blocks.CharBlock(max_length=120)
    table_head = TableHead()
    table_rows = blocks.ListBlock(TableRow())

    class Meta:
        template = 'wagtail_blocks/table.html'
```

You will notice that I have set the 'template' property in the 'Meta' class, so you will have to create that file too.

table.html

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

<table>
    <caption>{{ value.caption_text }}</caption>
    <thead>
    {% for header_text in value.table_head.table_head_text %}
        <th>{{ header_text }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for table_row in value.table_rows %}
        <tr>
            {% for table_row_text in table_row.table_row_text %}
                <td>{{ table_row_text }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally you can easily use your new TableBlock in any page like this

```
body = StreamField([
    ('table', TableBlock()),
])
```

Comment: Can you please accept my answer the correct answer ?

Comment: I delved into this further, it is a good solution if the first row of the table is always a table header. However, if I want to use the way Wagtail's TableBlock is set up, that is, the editor can choose to make the first row as header, or the first column as header, or both, this will not work though.

Comment: The TableBlock that Wagtail is using is handsontable:
https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/contrib/table_block.html

Comment: your question was not clear, you didn't specify that you wanted to use the default wagtail block "Table Block". I thought you were going for a custom one.

Comment: Your solution is still helpful, it gave me ideas about other uses! Thank you.